# How to redirect with params that are not shown in url?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app, and view like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=('POST', 'GET'))
def index():
...
return redirect(url_for(
            'checkout',
            data=json.dumps(data['data']),
            source=source), code=307
        )

@app.route("/checkout", methods=('POST', 'GET'))
def checkout():
    data = json.loads(request.args['data'])
    ...
```

everything works fine except after redirect I have url like

```
/checkout?source=&data={ ... }
```

but I want it to be clear, without params in url.
How can I reach it?

I tried changing/removing code param from redirect, neither worked.

Comment: You'd need to define `checkout` and its route to accept URL parts for `source` and `data`, although putting a JSON string in the middle of a URL will look version similar to what you have now. If `data` comes from the post body, though, your 307 will handle passing that on to the next page and you don't need to include it in the `redirect` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get these parameters because you explicitly tell flask to generate them:

`url_for("checkout", data=..., source=...)` creates the url to the checkout view includeing the parameters "data" and "source". If you don't want them leave them out.

But I see that you need to pass some data around. In your case it would make sense to use the session for that task:

```
from flask import session

# in the index view
session["data"] = your_data
session["source"] = your_source
return redirect(url_for("checkout"))

# in the checkout view
data = session.pop("data", None)
source = session.pop("source", None)
if data is not None and source is not None:
    # do your stuff
else:
    # checkout view was accessed before the index view
    # probably an error -> abort(400) ?
```

Two things to note:

1. You don't need to json-encode anything for the session, it can hold any python object
2. You need to provide a `SECRET_KEY` in your flask config if you want to use the session.

For more on sessions and how to provide a secret key look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions)